# Como configurar settings.py para usar django-tenant-schema?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django, multi-tenancy, schema

### Preciso configurar meu django para rodar a llb  `django-tenant-schema`

### Meu projeto não cria schemas e logo não consigo sincronizar meu banco com o projeto.

Estou tendo dificuldades em entender como está `llb` funciona e como devo configura-la, visto que tentei configurar baseado nos tutoriais da propria `llb`. Alguma dica do que está faltando?!

---

1. Minha **base de dados** já está estruturada. (**PostgresSQL**)
2. Meu **projeto** já está praticamente pronto(Apenas alguns ajustes após terminar essa parte).
3. Modelo de **schema** também já está pronto.
4. **Se for o caso**, deveria utilizar `django-tenants`? Parece bem similar...

---

Gostaria de saber se como estou configurando está correto, pois ao meu ver estou fazendo errado. Inclusive ao tentar criar dados para testar não está funcionando como deveria.

Este é meu **settings.py**:

```
SHARED_APPS = (
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app
    'dash',  # you must list the app where your tenant model resides in

    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # everything below here is optional
    # 'django.contrib.auth',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    # 'django.contrib.messages',
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
)

TENANT_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',

    # your tenant-specific apps
    'dash',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app

    'dash',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'login',
    'api',
    'correlator',  # Nome do projeto
]

TENANT_MODEL = "login.LoginBd"  # app.Model

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ('tenant_schemas.routers.TenantSyncRouter',)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend',  # O resto que não está aqui é desnecessario
```

Estrutura do Projeto é assim:
[image: Projeto]

LoginBD deve ter `auto_create_schema = True`?
Devo configurar mais algo nos modelos? `settings.p`y está configurado corretamente? Como insiro novos schemas? E dados para teste?

No site do django-tenant-schema vi algo que seria como `TENANT_MODEL_DOMAIN`. Devo utilizar? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá não sei se é exatamente a resposta que você espera.

Você precisará adaptar todo seu projeto.

a princípio uso o django-tenant-schemas(não é o django-tenant) e o django-tenant-users, crio um Model que herda a classe TenantBase responsavel por criar os Tenants(Schemas no banco de dados).
Exemplo:

```
> #settings.py TENANT_MODEL = loginbd.LoginBD
> 
> #loginbd/models.py
>         class LoginBd(TenantBase): # Este modelo cadastra os Tenants(Áreas)
>              name = models.CharField(max_length=50,
>                                 default=None,
>                                 verbose_name="Nome")
```

depois você precisa criar o model para criar os usuário que terão acesso aos tenants, que existirá um grupo no tenant_public e um grupo de usuário separado por tenant(schemas) que serão criados em seu cadastro do model anterior.

```
> #settings.py AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.TenantUser'
> 
> #users/models.py
>     class TenantUser(UserProfile):
>          name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100,)
```

entre outras configurações e adaptações.
Lembrando que os aplicativos SHARED_APPS servem para todos os tenants e o TENANT_APPS terão suas áreas particulares por tenant(schema).

Answer (score 0):

Para configurar `django-tenant-schemas` as instruções estão no [repositório](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) deles do github e no [readthedoc](https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), siga todas as instruções fornecidas para ter certeza que você não esqueceu nada

Comment: Desculpe se eu for grosseiro mas, você não acha que se eu criei um post no **stackoverflow** eu já não li a documentação no minimo umas 10 vezes e já tentei tudo que acho possível?

Da onde você acha que eu tirei o nome da biblioteca? Se tu tivesse aberto o mesmo link que mandou, perceberia que eu estou tentando configurar do modo que eles explicam, porem sem sucesso...

Comment: Sem problemas mas a sua pergunta é como configurar e na documentação já tem como fazer, se vc estiver tendo algum erro você deve detalhar pra que as outras pessoas que forem responderem pelo menos entender qual é o seu problema, você deve tá esquecendo de alguma coisa, tenta olhar nas issues do projeto se alguém tem o mesmo problema e se nada der certo faz tudo de novo

Comment: Claro, não tem problema eu complemento a pergunta, mas assim, o que você respondeu é inútil. Eu segui os passos(mal explicados) da biblioteca e não cheguei ao funcionamento, quem tem conhecimento sobre essa biblioteca, vai bater o olho no meu código e vai saber o que tem que ser feito, e é pra isso que esse fórum serve, para dividir conhecimento.... E falar o óbvio não é inteligente. *Agora* se você tivesse pedido pra complementar a questão eu entenderia.

Comment: Eu ainda não tenho esse privilégio kkkk, tem esse artigo do Vinta que uma empresa especializada em Django, eles explicam uma solução que já tem no Django https://www.vinta.com.br/blog/2017/multitenancy-juggling-customer-data-django/

Comment: Acho que tu confundiu as coisas, ao meu ver isso é uma forma que eles criaram de fazer sem llb, e acredito que seja melhor fazer via llb estável. Mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Answer (score 0):

> LoginBD deve ter auto_create_schema = True?

Esta opção deve serve para após salvar o cadastro ele criar todas estrutura de banco de dados, por padrão é True.

> No site do django-tenant-schema vi algo que seria como TENANT_MODEL_DOMAIN. Devo utilizar? Se sim, como?

Esta opção deve ser inserida no settings.py, ela aponta qual domínio os seus tenants irão usar, por exemplo:

```
tenant1.exemplo.com.br
tenant2.exemplo.com.br
```

Exemplo de configuração no settings.py

```
TENANT_MODEL_DOMAIN = 'exemplo.com.br'
```